# What is our stance on questions about asking about datasets?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions about asking about datasets? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Example:

> Subject: Dataset of cars with required steering effort
>
> I am looking for a data set listing car models along with the required steering effort (= how much force the driver needs to exert to steer the wheels of a car).

(I am aware that it would be on-topic on Open Data Stack Exchange)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that would be on topic here, especially not the example you give - it doesn't have anything to do with maintenance and repair.